# tfileproperties not working in my case in talend open studio

Tags: mongodb, talend

> I want to fetch file details like path of file, column names, and other things .In my job there are null values while using tfileproperties as shown in image added. look

if somebody can do something.

[image]

Comment: could you show what are the settings you are passing in tFileProperties ?

Comment: hey thanks, I got the solution !! actually i was passing a wrong excel file path that's why it gives null values.

Comment: you have to pass the file path in a context variable then pass in tFileProperties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Use  `tFileProperties` you have to pass a  `valid file Path`

What i suggest is to pass the file Path in a `context variable` as such

[image]

Then , pass the context variable in my case `file_Input`  in the `tFileProperties` as such  :

[image]

And if your files are stored in the same Folder you can use a `tFileList`  component see the link below :
https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/tfilelist/tfilelist-standard-properties

Comment: Thanks Ben you save me !!!

Comment: Can I asked more question from you Related to Talend open studio?? Do me a favour plzz check my post Regularly...